# Переключение активности у Input

Tags: jquery, html5

Есть блок с несколькими Input:

```html
<div class="payment-wrap">
  <form class="calculator">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <label class="fst-lbl" for="intro-class">INTRODUCTORY CLASS</label>
          <select id="intro-class" name="intro-class">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="intro-30">30 minutes</option>
            <option value="intro-60">60 minutes</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <h3 class="payment__cup">LESSON PLANS
        </h3>
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <label for="length">French course</label>
          <select id="length" name="length">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="General">General Course</option>
            <option value="Exams">Exams Preparation</option>
            <option value="Conversational">Conversational French</option>
            <option value="Business">Business French</option>
            <option value="Civilisation">Civilisation française</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <label for="students">For how many students</label>
          <select id="students" name="students">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="indiv">Individual</option>
            <option value="group">2-3 people</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <label for="duration">Lesson duration</label>
          <select id="duration" name="duration">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="lesDur-30">30 minutes</option>
            <option value="lesDur-60">60 minutes</option>
            <option value="lesDur-90">90 minutes</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <label for="validity">Plan validity</label>
          <select id="validity" name="validity">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1month">One month</option>
            <option value="3months">Three months</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <div class="submit-block">
            <p>This French course costs : <span value="0" id="result-culc"></span> euros</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Вопрос:
Как сделать так, что бы при значении `value` селекта `id="intro-class"` не равном `'0'`, все остальные селекты становились неактивными?

И обратно - при `value = '0'`, остальные селекты вновь становились активными?

И в конце, если возможно ответить еще на один вопрос:

Как в одной функции jQuery следить за изменением значений, которые вынесены в переменные? Мне главное синтаксис, чтобы функция работала. Может так?:

Чтобы легче было от моего ужаса оттолкнутся. Вот, правильно ли?:

```
(length,students,duration).addEventListener('change', function(){}
```

Как это всё реализовать на jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD**: с очищением полей

```js
$('#intro-class').change(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   if(val != 0) {
     $('select').not($(this)).attr('disabled', true);
     $('select').not($(this)).val('');
   }
   else {
     $('select').attr('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="payment-wrap">
  <form class="calculator">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <label class="fst-lbl" for="intro-class">INTRODUCTORY CLASS</label>
          <select id="intro-class" name="intro-class">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="intro-30">30 minutes</option>
            <option value="intro-60">60 minutes</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <h3 class="payment__cup">LESSON PLANS
        </h3>
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <label for="length">French course</label>
          <select id="length" name="length">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="General">General Course</option>
            <option value="Exams">Exams Preparation</option>
            <option value="Conversational">Conversational French</option>
            <option value="Business">Business French</option>
            <option value="Civilisation">Civilisation française</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <label for="students">For how many students</label>
          <select id="students" name="students">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="indiv">Individual</option>
            <option value="group">2-3 people</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <label for="duration">Lesson duration</label>
          <select id="duration" name="duration">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="lesDur-30">30 minutes</option>
            <option value="lesDur-60">60 minutes</option>
            <option value="lesDur-90">90 minutes</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <label for="validity">Plan validity</label>
          <select id="validity" name="validity">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1month">One month</option>
            <option value="3months">Three months</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-calc">
          <div class="submit-block">
            <p>This French course costs : <span value="0" id="result-culc"></span> euros</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Что касается второго вопроса, то всё зависит от того, какой именно результат Вы хотите получить при изменении. Если Вам надо просто отслеживать, изменился ли какой-то из селектов, то просто перечисляете их и навешиваете один обработчик:

```
$('#length, #students, #duration').change(function() { ... });
```

Если же результаты изменений разных селектов должны быть различны, то решение будет иным.

Comment: Всё работает. Помогли очень.
А по второму вопросу: мне бы форму записи с переменными, а не селекторами желательно бы.

Comment: Может знаете  - как чтобы и становились неактивными селекты и очищались их поля в придачу?

Comment: @Nice, а зачем Вам переменные? что именно Вы хотите делать-то?

Comment: @Nice, дополнил ответ - теперь с очищением полей

Comment: Чтобы не писать доллар и скобки. Я думал что такое возможно, но вы и так мне помогли, и с очищением полей еще)

Comment: @Nice, такое возможно: var length = $('#length'), students = $('#students'), duration = $('#duration'); дальше можете работать с переменными. но зачем эти лишние переменные? :)) jQuery для того и существует, чтобы можно было с помощью css-селекторов обращаться напрямую к элементам DOM

Comment: @Nice, сегодня на свежую голову понял, что можно ещё упростить код - добавил изменения в решение (так всё-таки более корректно, чем мой вчерашний вариант)